# Understanding the "do, end" syntax in routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Regarding the following bit of code:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'

  resources :articles do
    resources :comments
  end

  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

To my understanding, `Rails.application.routes.draw` is a method that accepts a block, and what's defined between the `do` `end` is the said block?

Comment: Yep, that's it. Contents of `routes.rb` is just plain ruby.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev thanks for the swift response!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write a block in Ruby in two ways:

In the short version code is surrounded by `{` and `}`. This version is mostly used for one line of code.

```
names.each { |name| puts name }
```

In the long version code is surrounded by `do` and `end`. This is the multiline version. The code sample you posted is a good example of a multiline block.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'

  resources :articles do
    resources :comments
  end

  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `resources` is a function that takes a block.

Internally the block is executed within the scope of the parent resource, the code for that looks like this (simplified)

```
def resources(resource, &block)
   ...
   begin
     # make resource the new parent before calling the block
     @scope.push(resource)
     # call the block
     yield
   ensure
     # restore the previous parent
     @scope.pop
   end
   ...
end
```

Like this the nesting of the resources and the nesting of your code in the `routes.rb` file are mirroring each other.

See here for the full code, https://github.com/rails/rails/tree.master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb

Comment: Actually, he was asking about `draw`, but `resources` is similar in that regard. :)

Comment: Thanks for providing the pseudo code for `resources` as well. Why must the yield be nested inside a `begin` `end` ?

Comment: @carpetfizz to make sure the scope is always restored even if there were an error in the block. An `ensure` is always execute even if there is an error.

Answer (score 0):

The ressources key word represent the crud RESTFULL functions (create, read, update, destroy) so when we put

> resources articles ==> create the crud routes for article model
>   and for every article we have comments so if we want to create a new comment for article we have to precise the article resource.

for example to create a new comment for article with 1 Id

```
blablabla.com/articles/1/comment/new
```

and if we want to destroy the comment with id 144 of article with Id 1

```
blablabla.com/articles/1/comment/144 on DELETE http request
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this isn't pertinent to the original question - for the sake of future readers

Answer (score 0):

If you open and see the draw method implementation at `/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.7@itildesk/gems/actionpack-4.2.11.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:408` you would get a better clarity.

It accepts a block of code. i.e. whatever is in between ***do*** and ***end*** and executes *instance_exec*, which in turn going to add all the resources or paths you mentioned to a variable of their routes internal.

> Whenever you encounter do-end block, just have a mind map that the code block is
>   being passed as a parameter, which will be executing
>   somewhere.